# Elasticsearch: Finding the overlap of one field against another

Tags: python, elasticsearch, aggregation, intersection

I'm trying to think of a way to do this in Elasticsearch without making multiple queries, or using `_mget` if necessary.

I have many documents with this structure:

```
{
  'location': 'Orlando',
  'agent_id': 395205, 
},
{
  'location': 'Miami',
  'agent_id': 391773,
},
{
  'location': 'Miami',
  'agent_id': 391773,
},
{
  'location': 'Tampa',
  'agent_id': 395205,
}
```

Where there are a fixed number of `location` values, but many unique `agent_id`s.

My ultimate goal is, given a list of locations, find the `agent_id`s that exist in all of them. So in the above example, given `['Orlando', 'Tampa']`, we get `[395205]` back because it exists in both. One location MAY have duplicate `agent_id`s (and this is expected behavior), so I can't use counts (eg. show me `agent_id`s that appear `n` times where `n = len(locations)`.

Another key here is that I'd like to actually return the hits if possible, rather than in an aggregate bucket. So ideally `top_hits` can be nested somewhere.

I'm thinking this may be possible using some clever filtering, or perhaps some rigid scoring, but I'm not sure how to approach those. I've got this working using multiple queries, but I'm finding the process too expensive and would like to simplify it if at all possible. I recognise that this may, in fact, not be possible. But curious to hear any other takes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Count of unique locations under an agent can be used to find common agents

Query:

```
{
  "query": { --> select docs with give location
    "terms": {
      "location.keyword": [
        "Orlando",
        "Tampa"
      ]
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "agents": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "agent_id",  ---> List of agents
        "size": 10
      },
      "aggs": {
        "location": {         ---> Unique locations under a agent
          "terms": {
            "field": "location.keyword",
            "size": 10
          }
        },
        "my_bucket": {
          "bucket_selector": {
            "buckets_path": {
              "count": "location._bucket_count" 
            },
            "script": "params.count==2" -->count of locations for agent, replace 2
                                        --> with needed count(number of locations)
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Result:

```
 [
      {
        "_index" : "index30",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "LXuksHABg1vns4B5FWL5",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "location" : "Orlando",
          "agent_id" : 395205
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "index30",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "MHuksHABg1vns4B5OmKC",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "location" : "Tampa",
          "agent_id" : 395205
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "aggregations" : {
    "agents" : {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
      "buckets" : [
        {
          "key" : 395205,
          "doc_count" : 2,
          "location" : {
            "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
            "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
            "buckets" : [
              {
                "key" : "Orlando",
                "doc_count" : 1
              },
              {
                "key" : "Tampa",
                "doc_count" : 1
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```

Comment: This is extremely helpful! Thank you!

Comment: Glad could be of help